# Increasing Prometheus storage retention

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have Prometheus server installed on my AWS instance, but the data is being removed automatically after 15 days. I need to have data for a year or months. Is there anything I need to change in my prometheus configuration?

Or do I need any extensions like Thanos? I am new to Prometheus so please be easy on the answers.

Comment: Prometheus supports remote_write mechanism for replicating data to [long-term storage systems](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage), so the data could be queried later from these systems. The most promising systems are Cortex, m3db and [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Edit the prometheus.service file

`vi /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service`

2. add `"--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y"` below to `"ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \"` line.

So the config will look like bellow for 1 year of data retention.

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=prometheus
Group=prometheus
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \
    --config.file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    --storage.tsdb.path /var/lib/prometheus/ \
    --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles \
    --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries \
    --web.external-url=http://34.89.26.156:9090 \
    --storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Is there a downside to increasing the retention time, slowness, or something else?

Comment: Depends on your data volume, if the data size will be huge, you will need more ram/cpu to fetch the same in to metrics

Answer (score 34):

There's the `--storage.tsdb.retention.time` flag that you can set when you start Prometheus. It defines how long data is kept in the time-series database (TSDB). The default is 15 days.

So, to increase the retention time to a year, you should be able to set this to something like:

```
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y
# or
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=365d
```

See the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#operational-aspects).

Comment: Can this be set in the yml?

Comment: No, it can only be set with command-line flags. It's an [immutable system parameter](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/).

Comment: Be careful with this answer, 'm' stands for 'minutes' not 'months' as described here: https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/prometheus/prometheus.1.en.html

Comment: To add some context to this answer, there's a reason the default is 15 days. Per the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#operational-aspects), _Prometheus's local storage is not meant as durable long-term storage._

Ensure your storage is suitably configured with durability if one year's worth of metrics is essential to operations.

Comment: @vitaminwater from the docs m seems to be minutes and there's no way to specify months (but you can specify weeks by 'w')

Comment: From [cmd/prometheus/main.go](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/bef6556ca566b47be52088466f36c1eaab4a2e45/cmd/prometheus/main.go) on GitHub: `Units Supported: y, w, d, h, m, s, ms.`.

Answer (score 11):

adding below in deployment yml file allowed me change storage retention days

```yaml
image: 'your/image path' 
args:
  - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
  - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=45d'
  - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
```

Comment: this should probably say that Docker installation is assumed.

Answer (score 9):

On Debian you do not have to edit the systemd-config. You simply can add the arguments to

```
/etc/default/prometheus
```

like so:

```
# Set the command-line arguments to pass to the server.
ARGS="--storage.tsdb.retention.time=60d"
```

Comment: in my case is different, I download the Prometheus from Bitnami using helm. and upgrade the values by editing the values to retention up to 10d, because the default is 10d. but seems not working at all. it does not even survive in 24 hours. i use ubuntu and install my Prometheus inside of the cluster. i tried to find in /etc/default/prometheus to add the arg. Unfortunately, I do not have the Prometheus file there. any solution? 
import the Prometheus or snapshot Grafana, the only temporary solution that I ever had, but still not tried yet.

Comment: This is what I had to do on Ubuntu after installing via apt

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu with prometheus installed via snap, edit `/var/snap/prometheus/current/daemon_arguments` and add `--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y` to the `ARGS=` line at the top.

Restart the prometheus snap: `systemctl restart snap.prometheus.prometheus.service`