# Prometheus retention time set to 1 year but not keeping data beyond default 15 days

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I've recently installed Prometheus and am using Grafana for reporting.

I set up Prometheus during installation to have retention time of 1 year using:

```
--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y
```

Now, we noticed from yesterday that data from 15 days prior wasn't showing up anymore. Is there something wrong with my code? Is `1y` not being recognised?

Comment: Did you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300232/1563297

Comment: Look at other flags also https://www.robustperception.io/configuring-prometheus-storage-retention

Answer (score 5):

You need to set command line options in ur startup file (f.e. prometheus.service)

```
--storage.tsdb.retention.size 120GB \                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--storage.tsdb.retention.time 1825d
```

In this example I set 120 GB as storage space and 5 years as timeframe to keep data