# How to increase jenkins prometheus plugin data retention?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, prometheus

We've installed prometheus plugin in our jenkins instance and the metrics are available in `https://jenkins-url/prometheus` endpoint. However the data available is only 2 days old. I'd like to know if there's a way to increase this data retention.

Jenkins Prometheus Plugin Configuration `org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.config.PrometheusConfiguration.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.config.PrometheusConfiguration plugin="prometheus@2.0.10">
  <urlName>prometheus</urlName>
  <additionalPath></additionalPath>
  <defaultNamespace>default</defaultNamespace>
  <jobAttributeName>jenkins_job</jobAttributeName>
  <useAuthenticatedEndpoint>true</useAuthenticatedEndpoint>
  <collectingMetricsPeriodInSeconds>120</collectingMetricsPeriodInSeconds>
  <countSuccessfulBuilds>true</countSuccessfulBuilds>
  <countUnstableBuilds>true</countUnstableBuilds>
  <countFailedBuilds>true</countFailedBuilds>
  <countNotBuiltBuilds>true</countNotBuiltBuilds>
  <countAbortedBuilds>true</countAbortedBuilds>
  <fetchTestResults>true</fetchTestResults>
  <processingDisabledBuilds>false</processingDisabledBuilds>
  <appendParamLabel>false</appendParamLabel>
  <appendStatusLabel>false</appendStatusLabel>
  <labeledBuildParameterNames></labeledBuildParameterNames>
  <collectDiskUsage>true</collectDiskUsage>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.config.PrometheusConfiguration>
```

[[image: Jenkins executor Panel]]

I tried exploring the prometheus plugin source code in [Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/prometheus-plugin/). Searched for keywords like retention, storage but couldn't find anything.
[PrometheusConfiguration-JavaDoc](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/plugin/prometheus/org/jenkinsci/plugins/prometheus/config/PrometheusConfiguration.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it all works: Prometheus plugin just exposes metrics (their current state), it doesn't store anything.

Data is stored by Prometheus. You can see information on how to change retention policy of Prometheus in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63213566/21363224).

Comment: Ok. I've a stupid question. If it doesn't store anything, how does it exposes 2 days data alone?

Comment: @vijayv, it means that prometheus collected data from jenkins for this 2 past days. Could it be that you installed plugin on 28.03 near 17 o'clock? If it's the case - than you don't need to change any settings, and just wait when Prometheus scrape more data.

Comment: We've this plugin installed for almost a year now. But only last month we setup this executor dashboard in grafana. Everytime we load, we only see 2 days data here.

Comment: Then look into your Prometheus. Copy query from your panel, go to Prometheus (something like `http://prometheus.company.local:9090/graph`), insert query and switch to Graph. You'll see how long into past prometheus have data. Also check status > command line flag there: you'll see retention policy. Investigate from there.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Looks like the retention size we had for prometheus was less for the amount of data we ingest. It's not an issue with jenkins prometheus plugin.